# pushing elements in an existing array object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, arrayobject

I have data that is a result from a query. I would like to insert some array variables of it. I have ID's then I tried to make a query and insert the query into a variable.

I have a data like these as a result of my query:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 27 [message] => {"msg_subject":"hello","msg_content":"world"} [date] => 2020-05-24 15:03:40 [parent_msg] => 0 ) )
```

now I want to insert a data inside the array object like the final result would be this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 27 [message] => {"msg_subject":"Hooy","msg_content":"Ok ra?"} [date] => 2020-05-24 15:03:40 [parent_msg] => 0 ) [read] => 0 )
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){                
     $this->db->select('mp.*');    
     $this->db->from('message_tbl mp');
     $this->db->join('message_tbl mc', 'mc.parent_msg = mp.id');                
     $this->db->where('mc.id',$row['msg_id']);
     $data = $this->db->get()->result();
        array_push($data,$row['read']);
    }
print_r($data);
```

then when I printed my data Here is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 27 [message] => {"msg_subject":"Hooy","msg_content":"Ok ra?"} [date] => 2020-05-24 15:03:40 [parent_msg] => 0 ) [1] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `$row['read']` value to the result object and then push that object to your `$data` array. Something like this should work:

```
$data = array();
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){                
     $this->db->select('mp.*');    
     $this->db->from('message_tbl mp');
     $this->db->join('message_tbl mc', 'mc.parent_msg = mp.id');                
     $this->db->where('mc.id',$row['msg_id']);
     $result = $this->db->get()->result()[0];
     $result->read = $row['read'];
     array_push($data, $result);
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: It gave me something like these : Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: As a side note, it's also possible that you can put another join in the original query to get the `read` value and not have to do an extra query for each result.

Comment: @Jerry It will make my query much complicated that's why i want to process it in PHP

Comment: @JcJohn did you add the `$data = array();` statement at the beginning?